# Copy data from SQL Server to Excel "NULL" instead of blank NUMBERS

Tags: sql-server, excel, null, formats

I copy data from a SQL Server result set and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet.  The NULL values need to appear as blanks in Excel, but the default behavior is to show the word, "NULL".  For text fields, I can apply ISNULL([field],'') in the original query.  But what about numeric fields?  I don't want it to be 0, it needs to be blank.  Is there a query based solution?  I keep forgetting to do find and replace.

Comment: Not that I know of... You could have your queries convert your numbers to varchar with something like  `numberCol=isnull(convert(varchar(32),numberCol),'')` but that's pretty silly.

Comment: The default "behavior" is not in Excel. It is how SSMS displays NULL in the output. And sure you can use the same ISNULL logic for a numeric column in Excel. Since the data is not strongly typed in Excel (everything is really just a string) it can display an empty string. For calculations Excel will treat an empty string as a 0.

Comment: SqlZim, I ended up using your super silly function nest.  Soon, I'll get to change this whole process.  Thanks your your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but do to low rep, i'll post as an answer. Excel will not show a blank by default for a number value when pasted into the worksheet. It will interpret (correctly) a blank data point as 0. Since you are willing to find and replace 0s with null values, it seems this is for presentation purposes. If that is the case, I'd suggest conditional formatting. Set when the cell's value = 0 make the text white. if you are applying any mathematics to this column, the effect of a null cell or a 0 cell are the same, thus no impact to formulas/functions.

Comment: Should have added this restriction: the Excel file cannot have any formulas or conditional formulas.  It was designed to be a tab-delimited text file with a .xls suffix.  File format is not under my control.  I need the output from SQL to be as close to the delivery format as possible.  Also, there are legitimate 0's in the data, so I cannot blanket replace them with blanks.

Comment: Is your find and replace process on a case-by-case basis? Is there is no way to save the file as a standard .xls or .xlsx file? Lastly, the data source must be shared with other users? You couldn't warehouse the data source locally and only share views of this data (i.e. pivot tables, linked tables, etc.)?

Comment: HAHAHA!  Best practices???  No.  I have just taken ownership of this project, and for now, I have to maintain it as it is.  So, tab-delimited .xls, with blanks instead of NULLs.

Comment: hmm, your case is tricky. the problem is excel is properly converting the blank cell values into 0s as the column is formatted as a number (NULL in respect to integers and floats is 0). In your case, it may be best to cast the field to a varchar first, then apply your isnull. i.e.     isnull(cast([field] as varchar), '')